# How do I sort the divs below on name and on the number

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I am trying to create two buttons with javascript. This button will sort the movies ascending and descending.

So I am trying to sort the full divs on the values that are in the h2 and h3. I don't know how to do this in JavaScript and this is a requirement.

So what I am trying to do is sort them by row. 
With the values that are in the col-md-5 h2 and h3.

```
<!-- Film 1 -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <a href="edge-of-tommorrow.html">
            <img class="img-responsive img-hover" src="img/edge-of-tommorrow-700x300.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <h2>Edge of Tommorrow</h2>
        <h3>8.6</h3>
        <h4>Tags: Science Fiction, Oorlog, Actie</h4>
        <p> Een Derde Wereldoorlog is begonnen, een oorlog van aliens tegen de mensheid. Een hoge officier (Tom Cruise) word naar het front gestuurd om te helpen bij de landing in Frankrijk en zo weer grond terug te veroveren op de aliens. </p>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="edge-of-tommorrow.html">Bekijk Film</a>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.row -->

<hr>

<!-- Film 2 -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <a href="a-million-ways-to-die-in-the-wild-west.html">
            <img class="img-responsive img-hover" src="img/a-million-ways-to-die-in-the-west-700x300.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <h2>A million ways to die in the Wild West</h2>
        <h3>7.2</h3>
        <h4>Tags: Comedy, Western</h4>
        <p>Een film waarbij je constant aan het lachen bent. Zodra de ene grap is afgelopen komt de volgende. Het gaat over een stuntelige schapenhoeder die voor de nieuwe mystrieuze vrouw in het stadje valt. Die toevallig getrouwd is met de gevaarlijkste scherpschutter van het Wilde Westen. En wat voor veel hilarische momenten zorgt.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="a-million-ways-to-die-in-the-wild-west.html">Bekijk Film</a>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: please show some attempt to solve yourself first. (as a side note, the title is *A million ways to die in the West* (Source: I work in a cinema ;P)). Could you not display this in a webgrid of some sort? (as it would then be sortable/etc)? you could also then be able to attach it some a DB, allowing for easy editing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i think this may help :

```
var movies = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.getElementsByClassName("row"));
var result = "";

//descending numbers
movies.sort(function(a, b){return b.getElementsByClassName("col-md-5")[0].getElementsByTagName("h3")[0].textContent - a.getElementsByClassName("col-md-5")[0].getElementsByTagName("h3")[0].textContent});

//ascending numbers
movies.sort(function(a, b){return a.getElementsByClassName("col-md-5")[0].getElementsByTagName("h3")[0].textContent - b.getElementsByClassName("col-md-5")[0].getElementsByTagName("h3")[0].textContent});

//descending Letters
movies.sort();

//ascending Letters
movies.sort();
movies.reverse;
movies.forEach(function(entry) {
    result += entry.innerHTML;
});
document.getElementById("Content").innerhtml = result;
```

add this to your html code :

```
<div id="Content">
     <!--Movies-->
</div>
```

Comment: I have been trying this but I can't get it to work even after many hours I tried so much things. I think I need to add a button that activates this JS. But I am new to javascript.. Do you have any more tips. I cant get anything to show up:P